# Header superimposed over text

Tags: header-footer, margins, lyx-layouts

The header in my report is superimposed on the text. I've tried altering voffset and header height but it didn't get me satisfactory results.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


%to get para numbers in the margins

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{numpar}
\newcommand{\np}[1][]{%
  \par
  \refstepcounter{numpar}%
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{\thenumpar}}%
    \qquad
  }%
  #1%
  \ignorespaces
}

%evidence counter
\newcounter{evidence}
\newcommand{\ev}{%
  \stepcounter{evidence}%
  \marginpar{\textbf{EV\theevidence}}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\begin{footnotesize}
Header line 1 \\Header line 2
\end{footnotesize}}

\rhead{\begin{footnotesize}
Header line 1\\Header line 2
\end{footnotesize}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Set the "\setlength{\headheight}{26pt}" in preamble.

Comment: As indicated in the log message `\headheight is too small`, so add `\setlength{\headheight}{35.0mm}` to your preamble. A few more tweaks are needed as well. But the  solution will solve the basic problem indicated by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geometry` package and adjust the `headheight` and `headsep`aration by adding

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,headheight=.4in,headsep=12pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%% This line added ------------------------->
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,headheight=.4in,headsep=12pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
%to get para numbers in the margins

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{numpar}
\newcommand{\np}[1][]{%
  \par
  \refstepcounter{numpar}%
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{\thenumpar}}%
    \qquad
  }%
  #1%
  \ignorespaces
}

%evidence counter
\newcounter{evidence}
\newcommand{\ev}{%
  \stepcounter{evidence}%
  \marginpar{\textbf{EV\theevidence}}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\begin{footnotesize}
Header line 1 \\Header line 2%          %%<--- a spurious space is removed.
\end{footnotesize}}

\rhead{\begin{footnotesize}
Header line 1\\Header line 2%          %%<--- a spurious space is removed.
\end{footnotesize}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]