# Text over the header with figure

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I'm putting a figure in the header of my article, but the text is getting superimposed in the header only on the first page. I think that the problem is with the figure because when I remove it, the problem disappears.

I tried [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152986/header-superimposed-over-text) but it did not help me with the problem

The code is above this line:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,headheight=.4in,headsep=12pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\includegraphics[scale=.11]{cortada.jpg}\\
SERVIÇO PUBLICO FEDERAL\\
UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE SERIGPE\\
PRO-REITORIA DE POS-GRADUACAO E PESQUISA}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2cm}
\title{[RASCUNHO] Brincando com cabeçalhos}
\author{José Joaquim Andrade}
\date{November 2018}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

% \maketitle

\section{First Section}

\lipsum
\lipsum[3-16]

\newpage

\section{Second Section}
\lipsum
\section{Second Section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

To clarify my question, a print screen of the problem is presented below:

[image: Figure with the text superimposed in the header]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How do you think anyone can resolve the clash between the tiny `headheight=.4in` and your bulky header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headheight is too small. To increase it with `\setlength{\headheight}{...}`

The necessary size will depend on the image and can be found as a warning in the `.log` file of your document. For a dummy image I used I for example got

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (28.90755pt): 
 Make it at least 66.0991pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

so I rounded up and used `\setlength{\headheight}{67pt}`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,headheight=.4in,headsep=12pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\includegraphics[scale=.11]{example-image}\\
SERVIÇO PUBLICO FEDERAL\\
UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE SERIGPE\\
PRO-REITORIA DE POS-GRADUACAO E PESQUISA}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2cm}
\title{[RASCUNHO] Brincando com cabeçalhos}
\author{José Joaquim Andrade}
\date{November 2018}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
\makeindex

\setlength{\headheight}{67pt}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle

\section{First Section}

\lipsum
\lipsum[3-16]

\newpage

\section{Second Section}
\lipsum
\section{Second Section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I've tried this strategy, but because of the margins, I thought that I was in the wrong direction. To set the margins, I'm using \usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,headheight=.4in,headsep=12pt,heightrounded]{geometry}, but I'm can't see any difference. Is it related to the header?

Comment: @JoséJoaquim You make the headheight veryyyyyyyyy small. Best is to read your .log file, it clearly says what to do